# How do I create a subtle placeinitial effect in a setuphead?

Tags: context

I would like the first character of my `\section` head (I'm using a fancy germanic font) to be at (for example) `\tfb` while the rest is at `\tfa`.

I've tried adding `\placeinitial` to the style, but that merely creates a very large (5-6 line) whitespace before the \section, without benefit.

Is there a trivial way of accomplishing this?

Sample code:

```
\definefontfamily[germanic][gothic][ltcgoudytextw01lombardcap]

\setuphead[section]      [style={\setupbodyfont[germanic]\tfc\placeinitial},number=no]

\setupinitial[color=black,font=ltcgoudytextw01lombardcap at 26pt,distance=1pt,n=1,location=text,]

\starttext
\section{Character}
\input knuth

But I want to achieve
\blank
\setupbodyfont[germanic]
{\tfd C}{\tfb haracter}
\setupbodyfont[modern]

\input knuth

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: @Herbert better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, this is quite convoluted, but I couldn't find a better solution... So: you lose the ability to set up your initial the way `placeinitial` allows, but if you're sure that you just want the first character to be bigger, here goes (I don't have your font, so I use pagella):

```
\setupbodyfont [pagella, 12pt]

\def\doChapterTitle#1%
   {\ctxlua{userdata.chaptertitle([==[#1]==])}}

\startluacode
  userdata = userdata or { }

  function userdata.chaptertitle(s)
    local initial, rest = s:sub(1, 1), s:sub(2, -1)
    context.bgroup()
    context.switchtobodyfont( { "30pt" } )
    context(initial)
    context.egroup()
    context(rest)
  end
\stopluacode

\define[1]\MyChapterTitle%
  {\doChapterTitle{#1}}

\setuphead [chapter]
           [number=no,
            deeptextcommand=\MyChapterTitle]

\starttext

\startchapter [title={Character}]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Cras tellus. 

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Result:

[image]